# refresh div when model saved or updated with rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have in **page 1** the next div:

```
<div>
  1
</div>
```

I have in **page 2** the next form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@car) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('.create_car') %>
<% end %>
```

I would like if it's possible after submit and save/persist in db the `@car` object from page 2, **refresh the div inside page 1 with some new content**.

Have I use a framework like `ember.js` or `backbone.js` or not necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly? What's the connection between pages? User has them open both at once?

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely going to need to do this using AJAX.  Try using jquery, which makes it significantly easier.  A good overview [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery?autoplay=true).